# Javascript Clicker customer queue buttons call the password

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button, queue

I have the code below (Javascript and HTML):

```js
function uppass(e) {
    var element = document.getElementById("newclient");
    let value = element.innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    ++value;
    let newValue=e.id +'  -  ' +value ;
    document.getElementById("newclient").innerHTML =  newValue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    clicked button in JavaScript
  </title>
</head>

<body style="text-align:center;">
  <header>
    <h1> Clicker customer queue window calling</h1>
  </header>
  <h4><b>For customers</b></h4>
  <center>
    <button id="c" class="button" onclick="uppass(this)" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;"> Common </button>
    <button id="f" type="button" onclick="uppass(this)" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;"> Fast </button>
    <button id="p" type="button" onclick="uppass(this)" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;"> Priority </button>
  </center>
  <h5>Your pass is: </h5>
  <h2 id="newclient" style="font-size: 12px; display: inline-block; padding-left: 20px;">0</h5>
<br><br>

<h4><b>Attendant Call</b></h4>

<button id="window1" type="button" onclick="funcao()" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;"> Window 1 </button>
  <button id="window2" type="button" onclick="funcao()" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;"> Window 2 </button>
  <button id="window3" type="button" onclick="funcao()" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;"> Window 3 </button>
  <button id="window4" type="button" onclick="funcao()" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;"> Window 4 </button>
</center>

<br><br>
<h5>Calling password number:</h5><h2 id="newclient" style="font-size: 12px; display: inline-block; padding-left: 20px;">0</h5>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to make "window" call the password created in the "Common", "Fast" and "Priority" buttons.
For example.
If the client creates a password in "Common", "priority" or "fast", the "window" will call that password.
But I'm having trouble creating this in javascript, maybe with array, and with the "if" method but it could be another way too.
The hardest part is:
"window1" calls the password "Priority" , if there isn't, it calls the password "Fast", if there isn't, calls the password "common" and if there isn't one, it does nothing.
"window2" and "window3" call the password "Fast" , if there isn't, call the password "Priority", if there isn't, call the password "Common" and if there is none, do nothing.
"window4" calls the password "Common" , if there isn't one, it calls the password "Priority", if there isn't, it calls the password "Fast" and if there isn't one, it doesn't do anything.

Each "window" has its button. When clicking the button, it verifies the next password to be called, displays the password on the panel, displays the "window" corresponding to the button and removes it from the queue. If there is no password in the queue, it does nothing.

Can someone help? Thanks

Code on  [https://jsfiddle.net/ofr8kv05/](https://jsfiddle.net/markmark/ofr8kv05/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are created for each queue:

- Common = `cq[]`
- Fast = `fq[]`
- Priority = `pq[]`

On each press of a Customer password, the password is added to the appropriate queue, and displayed.

On each window press, the `orderedQueue` is built based on the rules, the first password is displayed, and removed from both the `orderedQueue` and the matching individual queue/array (`cq[]`, `fq[]` or `pg[]`).

```js
let cq = [] // Common Queue
let fq = [] // Fast Queue
let pq = [] // Priority Queue

function uppass(e) {
    var newClient = document.getElementById("newclient")
    let value = newClient.innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")
    ++value
    
    // Add to appropriate queue
    switch (e.id) {
        case "c": // Common Queue
            cq.push(value)
            break
        case "f": // Fast Queue
            fq.push(value)
            break
        case "p": // Priority Queue
            pq.push(value)
            break
    }
    
    newClient.innerHTML = e.id + ' - ' + value

    //console.log("cq: [" + cq + "]")
    //console.log("fq: [" + fq + "]")
    //console.log("pq: [" + pq + "]")
}

function funcao(e) {
    let orderedQueue = []
    let callClient = document.getElementById("callclient")

    // Build orderedQueue
    switch (e.id) {
        case "window1":
            orderedQueue = pq.concat(fq.concat(cq))
            break
        case "window2": case "window3":
            orderedQueue = fq.concat(pq.concat(cq))
            break
        case "window4":
            orderedQueue = cq.concat(pq.concat(fq))
            break
    }

    if (orderedQueue.length == 0) {
        callClient.innerHTML = "No customers."
    } else {
        firstInQueue = orderedQueue.shift()

        // Remove firstInQueue from queue
        if (firstInQueue == cq[0]) {
            cq.shift()
            fromQueue = "c"
        } else if (firstInQueue == fq[0]) {
            fq.shift()
            fromQueue = "f"
        } else if (firstInQueue == pq[0]) {
            pq.shift()
            fromQueue = "p"
        }

        callClient.innerHTML = fromQueue + " - " + firstInQueue

        //console.log("orderedQueue: [" + orderedQueue + "]")
        //console.log("cq: [" + cq + "]")
        //console.log("fq: [" + fq + "]")
        //console.log("pq: [" + pq + "]")
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        clicked button in JavaScript
    </title>
</head>

<body style="text-align:center;">
    <header>
        <h1>Clicker customer queue window calling</h1>
    </header>

    <h4><b>For customers</b></h4>

    <button id="c" class="button" onclick="uppass(this)" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;">Common</button>
    <button id="f" type="button" onclick="uppass(this)" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;">Fast</button>
    <button id="p" type="button" onclick="uppass(this)" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;">Priority</button>

    <h5>Your pass is:</h5>
    <h2 id="newclient" style="font-size: 12px; display: inline-block; padding-left: 20px;">0</h2>

    <br><br>

    <h4><b>Attendant Call</b></h4>

    <button id="window1" type="button" onclick="funcao(this)" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;">Window 1</button>
    <button id="window2" type="button" onclick="funcao(this)" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;">Window 2</button>
    <button id="window3" type="button" onclick="funcao(this)" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;">Window 3</button>
    <button id="window4" type="button" onclick="funcao(this)" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;">Window 4</button>

    <br><br>

    <h5>Calling password number:</h5>
    <h2 id="callclient" style="font-size: 12px; display: inline-block; padding-left: 20px;">0</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It really worked with arrays, but is there a way to show the name of the box that is calling?
For example: when clicking on window 1, the name window 1 will be displayed in front of the password. The same if clicking on windows 2,3 and 4. So that the customer knows which window to go to. i'm trying, but i can not do this.

Comment: @markmark: In `funcao()`, `e` is the window button that was clicked. `callClient.innerHTML = fromQueue + " - " + firstInQueue` is doing the printing. Hint: try adding `name` to each button, then print `e.name`.